# making a rotating or swing effect with scriptaculous shake?

Tags: javascript, ajax, animation, scriptaculous, effects

I am trying to have an effect when moused over, the item does not shake from side to side, but slides sort of like a clock pendulum rotating from 180-90 degreeds (or whatever, I can't remember the exact numbers right now). Is this possible with scriptaculous or another js library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a library for JQuery that does what I want perfectly:

http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html