# The effect of swinging in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, effects

I would like to do the following effect using JavaScript. http://users.telenet.be/victor.suls/swingb.swf

How can I do this effect?

Comment: Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035995/making-a-rotating-or-swing-effect-with-scriptaculous-shake) of Stack Overflow.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035995/making-a-rotating-or-swing-effect-with-scriptaculous-shake) has been given as an answer below. Since that is link-only, I am preserving it here in case it is deleted by the review queue.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use canvas of HTML5, with canvas you can control every pixel of the pic. and you have to calculate the object's trajectory in math.